# Make the code work on each element and according to its date

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make countdown using javascript and some html elements.
The code works fine but the issue is i have three items here in my code:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
            <article>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="assets/img/blog/blog-author-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid post-author-img flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time datetime="2024-11-30 08:50:00">2024-11-30 08:50:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </article>
          </div><!-- End first post list item -->

  <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
            <article>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="assets/img/blog/blog-author-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid post-author-img flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time datetime="2024-11-30 08:50:00">2024-11-30 08:50:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </article>
          </div><!-- End first post list item -->

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to

var enddateTime = document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].getAttribute('datetime');


var countDownDate = new Date(enddateTime).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

So is it possible to get a countdown for 'datetime' according to each element date without repeating the function three times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to

var enddateTime = document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].getAttribute('datetime');


var countDownDate = new Date(enddateTime).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
let countDownValue = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "
changeTheCountDownValue(countDownValue);

  

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    changeTheCountDownValue("EXPIRED");
  }
}, 1000);

function changeTheCountDownValue(value)
{
    var countDownElements = document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
      for(let i=0;i<countDownElements.length;i++){
    countDownElements[i].innerHTML = value;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
            <article>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="assets/img/blog/blog-author-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid post-author-img flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time class="countdown" datetime="2024-11-30 08:50:00">2024-11-30 08:50:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </article>
          </div><!-- End first post list item -->

  <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
            <article>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="assets/img/blog/blog-author-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid post-author-img flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time class="countdown" datetime="2024-11-30 08:50:00">2024-11-30 08:50:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </article>
          </div><!-- End first post list item -->
```